# Json not getting actual data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am passing some values to MVC Controller and it is returning json value. Now the problem is that a controller side, value returned properly but when I check it in jquery, it is showing **undefined data.**

**Controller Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DeleteServices(List<Int32> serMapId)
{
  int success = -1;
  if (serMapId.Count > 0 )
  {
    int count = RequestDL.DelServices(serMapId);
    if (count > 0)
    {
      success = count;
    }
  }
  return Json(new { success });
}
```

**Jquery Ajax Script:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/CRM/DeleteServices",
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  success: function (result) {
   alert(result.success);
   if (result.success > 0) {
     alert("Service(s) deleted successfully");
   }
   else {
     alert("Service(s) not deleted successfully");
   }
  },
  error: function () {
   alert("Something goes wrong at server side.");
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `return Json(success);`

Comment: Your code looks good so far. Have you checked with fiddler whats transfered over the wire? Have you set a breakpoint in your javascript success handler and look what value result has?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, it is not working...

Comment: @Jan I have tried same code for other page and it is working fine and i don't know what problem it gets here...

Comment: I don't know, too. So the only chance is to open your debugging tools and take a look :) Check the value of result and check the response with fiddler!

Comment: @Jan it showing undefined value

Comment: And what was sent by the server in the raw HTTP response?

Comment: @Jan, I am not getting what you saying. Can you explain in deep?

Comment: Your browser talks to the webserver through the HTTP protocol. With a tool like fiddler you can take a look at the raw data that is being sent between the browser and the webserver. To diagnose your problem it would be valuable to see what data exactly the webserver is returning to the browser.

Comment: @Jan, So how to check it? I debugged both jquery and c# code, c# code returning valid value but jquery not getting valid value.

Comment: Download, install and start fiddler2.

Comment: @Jan, thanks for the suggetion. Now it is working. See Mattbo's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the response to this

```
return Json(new { success = success });
```

or

```
return Json(new { success });
```

Some quick testing produces these results:

```
//Returns 1
//this is not a valid JSON object
//If 'success' were a complex object, this would work as expected
return Json(success);

//Returns {"success":1}
return Json(new { success });

//Returns {"success":1}
return Json(new { success = success });
```

Comment: `new { success = success }` is identical to `new { success }`!

Comment: I was able to try this out this morning and the result is a lot less strange than it seemed :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

dataType:'json',

in $.ajax function

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/CRM/DeleteServices",
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
      dataType:'json',
    });
```

Comment: what will be your response data

Answer (score 0):

Try returning your success object this way for a GET request:

```
return Json(success, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Return your Json this way for a POST:

```
return Json(success);
```

Don't forget to decorate your method with HttpPost so your controller should look like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DeleteServices(List<Int32> serMapId)
{
  int success = -1;
  if (serMapId.Count > 0 )
  {
    int count = RequestDL.DelServices(serMapId);
    if (count > 0)
    {
      success = count;
    }
  }
  return Json(success);
}
```

Make sure your Ajax Request is formatted like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/CRM/DeleteServices",
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (result) {
   alert(result.success);
   if (result.success > 0) {
     alert("Service(s) deleted successfully");
   }
   else {
     alert("Service(s) not deleted successfully");
   }
  },
  error: function () {
   alert("Something goes wrong at server side.");
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your way but It is not working. Showing same error.

Comment: ASP.Net MVC response can get interpreted like text.  Be sure to include the content type as I have in the JQuery request.

Comment: Actually I better ask how are you sending data to the server? what format? Intercepting a form post? collecting the data ad building a JSON object?

Comment: I am passing an array like:var serMapIdArray = new Array();. pushing some values and finally: var postData = { serMapId: serMapIdArray };

Comment: IC well if you were hitting the controller fine before and getting the values you wanted, then only change the datatype on the ajax request.  The easiest thing to do would be to inspect the response in a program like Fiddler or in Firefox's Firebug